rearrangement of an infinte series
I was given the followig series : $S=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4} \dots $
which is just a rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series, such that every $3$ odd elements from the original series are followed by $2$ even elements, and repeating that.
I am asked to determine whether this series converges or diverges, and if it converges, calculate its sum.
I tried to approach this by doing some arithmetic manipulations such as multiplying the sum by some constant and then adding it to the original series, but nothing worked out. I can't determine that this series converges to the same limit as the alternating harmonic series because it is not absolutely conv.
any ideas on how to approach this?

I deleted my answer, as a duplicate of @Koro's generalization in his accepted answer to the linked post. For $a=3,b=2$, the result is (the series converges and) $S=\ln\sqrt6$.

You can write it as
$$ \sum _{k=0}^{\infty} a_k-b_k$$
where $a_k=\frac{1}{6k+1}+\frac{1}{6k+3}+\frac{1}{6k+5}$ and $b_k=\frac{1}{4k+2}+\frac{1}{4k+4}$.
Note that this notation doesn't change the sum, since I'm only putting pharanteses and not rearranging elements. Now some algbera gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4k+2)(4k+4)((6k+3)(6k+5)+(6k+1)(6k+5)+(6k+1)(6k+3))-(6k+1)(6k+3)(6k+5)(8k+6)}{(6k+1)(6k+3)(6k+5)(4k+2)(4k+4)}
$$
This sum we can now estimate more easily by computing the order of magnitude of the enumerator, and the denominator. If their difference is more than 1, the series will converge from the comparisation test, and if less than 1, it will diverge.
The leading coefficient of the denominator is $6^34^2k^5=O(k^5)$ and of the enumerator is $(4^2*3*6^2-6^3*8)k^4 + (...)k^3=O(k^3)$
So the difference is 2 and the series behaves like $1/k^2$, (i.e., limit of their qoutient is contant) which converges.

I really appreciate your taking the time to answer this, but how would you calculate the actual sum? i believe there must be a shorter more elegant solution here since this was given as a multi-choice question worth only a couple of points on the test..

@JohannCarlFriedrichGauß: If this is a multiple-choice question then you should add that information (and the possible answers) to your question. It might be possible to exclude some answers without computing the exact sum.

You can split the sum to something like $A*\sum 1/k^2 + B * \sum 1/k^3 + C * \sum 1/k^4 + D * \sum 1/k^5$ and use these sums as baselines.

@Amit: what you say about parentheses just is not true. I can insert parentheses into the divergent $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ to get the convergent $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-1)$. Your proof is repairable, but as it stands it won't do.

Note that @Koro's generalization in his accepted answer to the linked post simultaneously proves the convergence and finds the limit. For $a=3,b=2$, his result is $S=\ln\sqrt6$.
